# How to view magit's current repository?

Tags: magit

[According to the Magit manual](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Status-buffer.html) the combination `C-x g` (`magit-status`) shows

> the status of the current Git repository in a buffer.

How can I view what the current Git repository is, i.e. the full path to it or alternatively the path relative to my home directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Proposal 1

For any Emacs buffer, you can invoke `M-x pwd` in order to display the current working directory, as determined by variable `default-directory`.

#### Proposal 2

The user option `magit-buffer-name-format` determines the name of Magit buffers and always contains the format specifier `%t`, which corresponds to the top-level directory of the repository's working tree.

The user option `magit-uniquify-buffer-names` defaults to `t`, which results in `%t` expanding to an abbreviated and uniquified representation of the current top-level directory.

If you don't mind the increased hogging of mode line real estate, you can set `magit-uniquify-buffer-names` to `nil` (e.g. via `(setq-default magit-uniquify-buffer-names nil)`) in order to have the full directory path displayed in the mode line (and as part of the name) of each Magit buffer.

#### Proposal 3

Following [Kyle Meyer's suggestion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32989/how-to-view-magits-current-repository#comment50925_32994), you could write your own command along the lines of

```el
(defun my-git-pwd (&optional insert)
  "Show the toplevel of the current repository.
With prefix argument INSERT, insert the current default directory
at point instead."
  (interactive "P")
  (magit-with-toplevel
    (pwd insert)))
```

#### Proposal 4

If you don't want to waste any horizontal space in the `mode-line` as suggested in (2), you can instead "waste" a single line in the status buffer itself:

```el
(magit-add-section-hook 'magit-status-headers-hook
                        'magit-insert-repo-header)
```

You can control where this additional information appears, see `magit-add-section-hook`'s doc-string.

Comment: Regarding Proposal 1: the current working directory is not necessarily the current Git repository.

Comment: Regarding Proposal 2: And what if I do mind the increased hogging of mode line real estate? Is there no way of querying magit for the path the to current Git repository (the one whose status will be displayed when the combination `Cx g` is executed)?

Comment: @EvanAad These two proposals are off the top of my head, I'm looking into it as we speak out of my own curiosity. Perhaps I should have written "possibility" instead of "proposal".

Comment: I understand. By the way, how can I view and set the user options you mentioned?

Comment: @EvanAad Have you come across a case where the current working directory (as reported by variable `default-directory`) does not correspond to the current Git repository? Judging from a cursory glance at Magit's source, such a situation would probably constitute a bug.

Comment: @EvanAad You can view the documentation and edit the state of any one user option via `M-x customize-option RET <variable name> RET` and of a whole customisation group via `M-x customize-group RET <group name> RET`. In both cases the relevant package should be loaded first, otherwise Emacs may not yet be aware of the user option and group. Both Magit user options I mention are included in the `magit-buffers` group.

Comment: `magit-toplevel` will return the directory that Magit considers to be the root of the current repo.