# provide optional parameter for magit

Tags: magit, git

I am tracking my dotfiles by using [this](https://antelo.medium.com/how-to-manage-your-dotfiles-with-git-f7aeed8adf8b) approach. This is very useful method to track files which are in different locations.

Short summary of the blog.

```
alias dotfiles='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'

dotfiles add newfile
dotfiles commit -am "add new file"
etc..
```

Since it's bash alias, I couldn't fınd the way to integrate this function with **magit**.

**Question:**

How I can use magit graphical interface like `dotfiles-magit-status` and look for changed files for this repository?

Kind of function like `M-x dotfiles-magit-status` is accepted.

**Links same approach:**

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11070797

**Maybe helps:**

- [How to view magit's current repository?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32989/how-to-view-magits-current-repository/32994#32994)

Comment: Did you see https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ot92l3/fluff_sharing_my_first_experience_using_emacs_and/?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> alias dotfiles='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'
> ```

I am under the impression that the only "problem" that this solves is that you typically cannot do `git clone URL $HOME` because $HOME already exists. I recommend you do this instead:

```
git clone URL /tmp/home
mv /tmp/home/.git $HOME/.git
rm -rf /tmp/home
cd $HOME
```

The cost of the "dotfiles approach" however is high: you now have to teach Magit and probably many tools to come about this complication. Anyway, if you still want to do it, at https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ot92l3 someone else seems to have figured out how to make the pig fly.